# COCOAPODS Validation i386 error

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, cocoapods

I'm trying to create my own POD for iOS with my code and some external libraries and dependencies. The Example attached compiles and build the app correctly with XCODE.

But when I'm about to validate with:

```
$> pod lib lint --allow-warnings --verbose --no-clean
```

the code I get this errors. It seems like an architecture problem related with the scheme but I've had no luck figuring out whats wrong in the settings.

```
** BUILD FAILED **


 The following build commands failed:
Ld /Users/marcsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eszacdypuufiakgbloohgxurnwhy/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/i386/App normal i386
Ld /Users/marcsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eszacdypuufiakgbloohgxurnwhy/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/App normal x86_64
CreateUniversalBinary /Users/marcsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eszacdypuufiakgbloohgxurnwhy/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.app/App normal i386\ x86_64
GenerateDSYMFile /Users/marcsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eszacdypuufiakgbloohgxurnwhy/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.app.dSYM /Users/marcsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eszacdypuufiakgbloohgxurnwhy/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.app/App
CodeSign /Users/marcsu/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eszacdypuufiakgbloohgxurnwhy/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/App.app
(5 failures)
Testing with xcodebuild.
```

After checking all the dependencies. The problem is using de GoogleMaps.framework, GoogleMapsCore.framework & GoogleMapsBase.framework in **s.vendored_frameworks**

No solution yet...

Comment: Is there some more of the build log from before the ** BUILD FAILED ** line? The section you posted tells you which commands failed, but not why.

Comment: No, there's no more details even using the verbose parameter about this message after the build error:

    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.

Comment: I've tryed also to create a i386 scheme simulator with no luck
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23950096/generate-simulator-build

Comment: Edit your question to show your Podspec.  That might provide some helpful hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quiet a long time we sort out to figure out the problem. We were using in our POD the GoogleMaps library included manually GoogleMaps.framework, GoogleMapsBase.framework and GoogleMapsCore.framework. (We cannot use it as regular pod dependencies because conflict with other swift libraries)

Also we where using the google maps utils library. 
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils

And we where including the headers of this library as public header libraries in the s.public_header_files references. That cause a those validation error.

Anyway I let my podspec file here if somebody gets in the same issue. Thank you all, feel free to comment.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name             = 'Core'
    s.version          = '0.1.0'
    s.summary          = 'Core. Core APP for APPS.'


    s.description      = <<-DESC
                        Core is the heart of all the APPS instances and APPS. Includes all the major assets and the resources for optimize all the system. Anyway the wind blows.
                        DESC

s.homepage         = 'https://core.git'
# s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'Moblie Department' => 'mail@core.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://core.git', :tag =>     s.version.to_s }

s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'

#tot el codi que s'ha de compilar
s.source_files = 'Core/Classes/**/*.{h,m,swift}',
             'Core/PrivateClasses/GoogleAnalyticsServices/*.h',
                 'Core/PrivateClasses/GoogleConversionTracking/**/*.h',
             'Core/PrivateClasses/GoogleMapsUtils/**/*.{h,m}',
             'Core/PrivateClasses/ZLib/*.h',
             'Core/PrivateClasses/XMLParser/*.h'

s.requires_arc = true

#les classes que seran publiques
s.public_header_files = 'Core/Classes/**/*.h',
                        'Core/PrivateClasses/GoogleAnalyticsServices/*.h'
                    'Core/PrivateClasses/GoogleConversionTracking/*.h'
                    'Core/PrivateClasses/XMLParser/*.h'
                    'Core/PrivateClasses/ZLib/*.h'



s.framework = 'CoreData','SystemConfiguration', 'Accelerate', 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreLocation', 'CoreText', 'GLKit', 'ImageIO', 'OpenGLES', 'QuartzCore', 'UIKit', 'AdSupport'
s.vendored_framework   = 'Core/Dependencies/GoogleMaps.framework', 'Core/Dependencies/GoogleMapsBase.framework', 'Core/Dependencies/GoogleMapsCore.framework', 'Core/Dependencies/Crashlytics.framework', 'Core/Dependencies/Fabric.framework'
s.vendored_libraries = 'Core/PrivateClasses/GoogleAnalyticsServices/*.a', 'Core/PrivateClasses/GoogleConversionTracking/*.a'
s.xcconfig = {'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-ObjC',
          'CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES' => 'YES',
          'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(inherited) $(SRCROOT)',
          'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' =>'$(inherited)     $(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2 $(SRCROOT)',
          'ARCHS' => '$(inherited)',
          'VALID_ARCHS' =>'$(inherited)'}

s.library = 'z', 'c++', 'xml2'

   s.resource_bundles = {
        'Core' => ['Core/**/*.{png,jpg,xib,strings}']
   }


s.dependency 'Floaty', '~> 3.0.0'
s.dependency 'Charts', '~> 3.0.2'

s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.1.0'
s.dependency 'MBProgressHUD'
s.dependency 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.11'
s.dependency 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 4.11'
s.dependency 'NSHash', '~> 1.1'
s.dependency 'UITextField+Shake', '~> 1.1'
s.dependency 'UIView+Shake', '~> 1.1'
s.dependency 'SVPullToRefresh'
s.dependency 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.8'
s.dependency 'AQSInstagramActivity', '~> 0.1'
s.dependency 'AQSTwitterActivity', '~> 0.1'
s.dependency 'SSZipArchive', '~> 1.8.1'
s.dependency 'UIAlertView+Blocks', '~> 0.9'
s.dependency 'UIActionSheet+Blocks', '~> 0.9'
s.dependency 'FSLineChart', '0.1.4'
s.dependency 'PESGraph', '~> 0.2'
s.dependency 'UIScrollView+Direction', '~> 1.0'
s.dependency 'SMCalloutView', '~> 2.1'
s.dependency 'EDSemver', '~> 0.3'
s.dependency 'UIButton+MiddleAligning'
s.dependency 'UIView+Border', '~> 1.0'

s.dependency 'LCBannerView'
s.dependency 'XLForm'
s.dependency 'MBProgressHUD'
s.dependency 'sqlite3'

end
```